# Mysql2, How to get last query result when i enable MULTI_STATEMENTS

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I use following:

```
cnn = Mysql2::Client.new(username: 'root', password: 'root', hostname: 'localhost', port: 3306, database: 'ro_cmds_plus_prod', flags: Mysql2::Client::FOUND_ROWS | Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
)

r = cnn.query('select "line 1"; select "line 2";').to_a
puts "r:#{r} ---- #{File.basename __FILE__}:#{__LINE__}"
```

and get

```
r:[{"line 1"=>"line 1"}] ---- exe.rb:17
```

My question is how to get

```
r:[{"line 2"=>"line 2"}] ---- exe.rb:17
```

Comment: Why not just two queries?

Comment: @spickermann, I try to use it in low performance vps, 2 querys need 2 times hard resource, I hope it slim

Answer (score -1):

Use the #next_result method of the Client object. Cf. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#multiple-result-sets

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: A Link is all well and good but you should elaborate on the reason why that is the right answer. Show code in use or relate it to the original question. @LW001 is correct that simple answers like this are likely to be deleted.